# couldn't run test in a modular rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Before I ask my question, I like you to see the structure of my modular rails app, in which apps are engines and plugged into Domain/Parent empty app having only configurations.

See image below:

[image: Modular Rails App]

However, when I run test with `rails test` or `rake test` in the domain/parent directory that has nothing aside configuration, I get:

[image: Test result]

However, I can run rake tasks like `bundle install`,`rake db:migrate` etc from the root of the app or domain/parent directory successfully because the engine app is plugged into the root of the app. So it baffles my why `rails test` or `rake test` does not work.

I proceeded and cd into engines, into the root app inside the engine and I ran `rails test` or `rake test` or `rails test test/models/csv_importer/user_test.rb` but I get a different thing. See it below:

[image: csv module testing]

I did the response but test didn't still run

How do I test a modular rails app? Any help is appreciated.

When I run: `rake db:test:prepare` from the root of the engine, I get:

[image: test db prepare]

Comment: do rake db:test:prepare

Comment: @RomanchSharma `rake db:test:prepare` inside the engine or at the domain/parent directory?

Comment: inside the engine

Comment: still doesn't do anything

Comment: have you run rails db:test:prepare test/models/csv_importer/

Comment: can you please show me the screen shot @Afolabi Olaoluwa Akinwumi

Comment: @RomanchSharma Kindly see update. I added the picture

Comment: how you done settings for db in your engines/csv_importer/lib/csv_importer/engine.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fix the problem. What I had to do is:

> From the root of the engine application (which is `csv_importer` as shown in the image in the question), I ran the following rails tasks:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Then when I run `rails test`, my test starts running.

[image: rails test]